# Need to understand how to format controls in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, css, alignment, stylesheet, html

Sorry for asking something basic here but I have not been able to apply right approach in formatting controls.

Below is a part of the code in ASPX page. I am failing in formatting it properly. I need some help here about what to consider and how to do it. Below is what the output looks like.

[image]

I would like the textbox (or dropdown) to align to it's label correctly. I know I haven't used stylesheet here but wanted to know if I can achieve without stylesheet. Even if stylesheet is required to achieve format, please suggest what to consider and how to proceed.

What is in ASPX page is below,

```
<div runat="server" id="DivCCInfo">
<fieldset class="CreditCardInformation">
    <legend>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="CCHeaderLabel" Text= "Credit Card Information" />
    </legend>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="CreditCardHolderLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CreditCardHolder" Text="Cardholder's Name" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="CreditCardHolder" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" MaxLength="30" Width="300" style ="left:-100px" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="CreditCardTypeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CreditCardType" Text="Credit Card Type" />
        <asp:Label ID="CreditCardNumberLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CreditCardNumber" Text="Credit Card Number" />
        <asp:Label ID="ExpirationLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ExpirationMonth" Text="Expiration Date"  />
        <asp:Label ID="CVVLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CVV" Text="CVV Code" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="CreditCardType"  Width="105">
            <asp:ListItem Text="VISA"  Value="VISA" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="MasterCard" Value="MasterCard" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Discover" Value="Discover" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Amex" Value="Amex" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="CreditCardNumber" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" MaxLength="16" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ExpirationMonth" Width="40">
            <asp:ListItem Text="01" Value="01" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="02" Value="02" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ExpirationYear" Width="60">
            <asp:ListItem Text="2012" Value="2012" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="2013" Value="2013" />
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:TextBox ID="CVV" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"   MaxLength="4" Width="50"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a fast way of doing this using [`<table>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) HTML element:

Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label
                 ID="CreditCardTypeLabel"
                 runat="server"
                 AssociatedControlID="CreditCardType"
                 Text="Credit Card Type" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label
                 ID="CreditCardNumberLabel"
                 runat="server"
                 AssociatedControlID="CreditCardNumber"
                 Text="Credit Card Number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label
                 ID="ExpirationLabel"
                 runat="server"
                 AssociatedControlID="ExpirationMonth"
                 Text="Expiration Date"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label
                 ID="CVVLabel"
                 runat="server"
                 AssociatedControlID="CVV"
                 Text="CVV Code" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList
                 runat="server"
                 ID="CreditCardType"
                 Width="105">
                 <asp:ListItem
                      Text="VISA"
                      Value="VISA" />
                 <asp:ListItem 
                      Text="MasterCard"
                      Value="MasterCard" />
                 <asp:ListItem
                      Text="Discover"
                      Value="Discover" />
                 <asp:ListItem
                      Text="Amex"
                      Value="Amex" />
             </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox
                 ID="CreditCardNumber"
                 runat="server"
                 CssClass="TextBox"
                 MaxLength="16"
                 Width="120">
             </asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList
                 runat="server"
                 ID="ExpirationMonth"
                 Width="40">
                 <asp:ListItem
                      Text="01"
                      Value="01" />
                 <asp:ListItem
                      Text="02"
                      Value="02" />
             </asp:DropDownList>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ExpirationYear" Width="60">
                  <asp:ListItem Text="2012" Value="2012" />
                  <asp:ListItem Text="2013" Value="2013" />
             </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox
                 ID="CVV"
                 runat="server"
                 CssClass="TextBox"
                 MaxLength="4"
                 Width="50">
             </asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just place your controls inside the table elements and they'll align perfectly allowing you to even left/center/right align them if you desire.

Comment: Why the downvote? Don't like tables? I like to use them for simple scenarios like this one with only 2 rows. They work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I didn't downvote. The team here don't want me to use tables concept but I will keep that as the last option. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I just tried the above. How do I make left aligned or I want the first column to start from 0px itself?

Comment: @NewCoder: do this `<tr align="left">` or `<td align="left">` in the column where you want to align the content. Possible values for align property are: left, center or right. You can also do: `<table width="100%" align="left">`. Hope you get the idea. Let me know if you have any doubts...

Comment: I am facing one issue and I think it is with the RequiredFieldValidators. I have these validators for every textbox and I guess these are adding one line of display which when page is loaded  shows that many blank lines. Do you know how to work with  these RequiredFieldValidators. I tried the display=dynamic but no much success.

Comment: I think this should be a new question. Ask a new question and upload a screenshot so that we can see what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use css you could try something like this

set the width of the label to something

```
       <asp:Label ID="CreditCardNumberLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CreditCardNumber" Text="Credit Card Number" Width="200"/>
```

set the width of the text box to the same width

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="CreditCardNumber" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" MaxLength="16" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
```

now when writing HTML put label with set width then space `&nbsp;` then another label with set width , the next line is text box with set width then space `&nbsp;`

I wouldn't reccommend using tables for styling forms , I would stick to using tables for displaying tables of data

Also I haven't used the  Width property in asp.net in a while , I usually use css , it might not be set properly in your code I think it might be `Width="120px"` instead of `Width="120"`

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. If I were to use stylesheet, how do I proceed consider the display I am looking for? appreciate your help.

Comment: that can't really be explained in an answer , Google css positioning , and you can see examples of how to position stuff relative to parents and elements around - like anything after a little practice you can just look at a form an know the css immediatly at first it will take a little practice

Comment: I could write it for you real quick for you - but SO is really more for if you run into problems writing it yourself to get help

Answer (score 1):

You can either use div's setting the width explicitly and float: left or you can do it with a table as suggested.  Randomly putting items on a page without containers and expecting to get them aligned is a feeble and time wasting attempt.

Here is a possibility (untested and adjust div sizes for what you need):

```
<div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <asp:Label ID="CreditCardHolderLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CreditCardHolder" Text="Cardholder's Name" />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="CreditCardHolder" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" MaxLength="30" Width="300" style ="left:-100px" ></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div style="clear: both; width: 200px;">
    <asp:Label ID="CreditCardTypeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CreditCardType" Text="Credit Card Type" />
    <br />
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="CreditCardType"  Width="105">
        <asp:ListItem Text="VISA"  Value="VISA" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="MasterCard" Value="MasterCard" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Discover" Value="Discover" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Amex" Value="Amex" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <asp:Label ID="CreditCardNumberLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CreditCardNumber" Text="Credit Card Number" />
    <br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="CreditCardNumber" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" MaxLength="16" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <asp:Label ID="ExpirationLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ExpirationMonth" Text="Expiration Date"  />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ExpirationMonth" Width="40">
        <asp:ListItem Text="01" Value="01" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="02" Value="02" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ExpirationYear" Width="60">
        <asp:ListItem Text="2012" Value="2012" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="2013" Value="2013" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <asp:Label ID="CVVLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CVV" Text="CVV Code" />
    <br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="CVV" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"   MaxLength="4" Width="50"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: :Thanks for the inputs. If I were to use div's setting, how can I proceed. Please share your inputs on the same.